# Creating a custom formula in Google Sheets without scripting, but instead based upon another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-custom-function

Ive made a custom calculator in a google sheet, the calculator accepts 5 inputs (arguments) on row 1, rows 2-50 is where is runs the calculation, and the result comes out in row 51.

This calculator is very easy for the end user to use, as they just input data on row 1 and get the answer on row 51. But i would like to be able to use the calculator as a custom function elsewhere in the spreadsheet, the the 5 inputs would become the 5 arguments for the formula. Something like

`=CustomCalc(a1,b1,c1,d2,e2)`

I know this is possible using Google Spreadsheet scripting but is it possible to do without scripting ?

Answer (score 0):

Custom functions are created using Google Apps Script, so no, it's not possible to create a custom function without scripting.

The alternative is to use an add-on or third-party app, maybe one that use Artificial Intelligence, low-coding apps, etc, to do the scripting job for you or to hire someone for that.

References

- https://support.google.com/docs
- https://developers.google.com/sheets